# Pandoc IPython notebook loses some Mathjax

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mathjax, pandoc

The problem I have is that I have an IPython notebook with some formulas written in MathJax. It is rendered fine in the notebook itself, but when I try to export it, most of my formula is gone!

Here's a small reproducible example:

I type

```
$ \int \cfrac{ 2 p(\vec{x}) d\vec{x}}  { \frac{1}{P(\omega_1 | \vec{x})} + \frac{1}{P(\omega_2 | \vec{x})} }$
```

It renders well inside the notebook:

[image]

But when I click file -> print preview, what I get is just a lonely plus sign:

[image]

In the sources I see this:

```
<p>$  {  +  }$</p>
```

So the entire formula is gone! What could be the reason?

My environment:

- Windows 7
- Anaconda-2.0.1-Windows-x86_64
- Python 2.7.7
- IPython 2.3.0
- pandoc 1.13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandoc you require a non-space character after the opening dollar and a non-space chacter before the closing dollar.

From the [documentation](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#math)

> Anything between two $ characters will be treated as TeX math. The
>   opening $ must have a character immediately to its right, while the
>   closing $ must have a character immediately to its left. Thus, $20,000
>   and $30,000 won’t parse as math. If for some reason you need to
>   enclose text in literal $ characters, backslash-escape them and they
>   won’t be treated as math delimiters.

Comment: Indeed, removing spaces did help. Thanks